# Display yes or no based on percentage

Tags: php, vb.net

I am trying to find a simple way to display "yes" and "no" based on a percentage.
this is just an example but on vb.net I can set a static and do something like this (70% and 30%)

```
        Static iNo As Long, iYes As Long
        If iNo > iYes * 0.42 Then
            iYes = iYes + 1
            Return False 'this is the 70%
        Else
            iNo = iNo + 1
            Return True 'this is the 30%
        End If
```

how exactly can I accomplish something this simple using PHP?

Comment: Why not give us some PHP code? We love PHP code. Yes we do!

Comment: What exactly have you tried?  If you expect people to put time and effort into their answers, the least you can do is put time and effort into your question; showing us what you've tried and why it hasn't worked helps us from not suggesting things you know don't work for your situation.

Comment: how can I set a static dim with php ?

Comment: @XK8ER Show us what you've tried and we'll try to help; this place isn't us doing your work for free.

Comment: most of the users here are pricks! all im trying to do is ask someone to point me in the right direction not "do work for free"

Comment: @XK8ER Insults?  I'm asking you what you've tried.  Try something and come back to us.

Comment: @XK8ER And when you expect us put time, and effort into our answer for you, the **least you can do is show us what you've tried**.

Comment: @XK8ER - Guess it takes one to know one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$numVotes = 100;
$trueVotes = 70;
$falseVotes = 30;

function addVote($boolVote){

    $numVotes++;
    if($boolVote)

       $trueVotes++:
       return $trueVotes * $numVotes / 100; //percent of true votes
    }
    else{

       $falseVotes++;
       return $falseVotes * $numVotes / 100; //percent of false votes
}

$newVote = true;
$percent = addVote($newVote);

($newVote)$strVote = "true":$strVote = "false";

echo sprintf("The vote is %s and the percent is %01.2f", $strVote, $percent);
```